# Linux: Open the latest file in a command line

Tags: linux, command-line

I use evince to open a .pdf file. I know how to find the latest file by

```
ls -Art | tail -n 1
```

Is there a way to use only one command line to combine the above two, to "open the latest file?" Or, if not possible, in the second line, I can let my last result, e.g., latest.pdf to pop up when I use evince?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just pass your command to evince:

```
evince $(ls -Art | tail -n 1)
```